# Bootstrap nav bar not clickable on mobile iPhone

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I know this question has been asked many types, but I haven't been able to fix my issue based on other answers. I have a nav bar that works on desktop (and on some desktop mobile emulators with developer tools). However, it doesn't work on my iPhone. It collapses into the three lines, but they aren't clickable. Thoughts on what I am doing wrong.

Website: https://begolden.app

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/static/dashboard/media/g_transparent_300.png" width="35" height="35" alt="">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard/mydatadashboard/">Scores</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard/intervention_selection/">Interventions</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard/myhabitdashboard/">Tracking</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard/mydata/">Raw Data</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Current User: kimberly.mcmanus@gmail.com</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/accounts/logout/?next=/dashboard/mydata/">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="myclass">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center"><u>Current lab values</u></h2>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-light table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Lab Test</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Units</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center"><u>Current habit data</u></h2>
      <br>

      <table class="table table-light table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Habit Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center"><u>Current text data</u></h2>
      <br>

      <p>There is no text data yet for this user</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML and not your template code. Also include your custom CSS, if any.

Comment: I updated the code to be the rendered html and included a link to the css

Comment: Links to code aren't sufficient. Please see [ask]. We should see a demo of your situation _here_.

Comment: Protip: don't use line breaks for spacing, especially when Bootstrap provides [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) for you. That's not what they're for.

Comment: And... you're loading Bootstrap 5 CSS and Bootstrap 4 JavaScript. That doesn't seem wise (and may be the problem). Please tag your actual version and correct the snippet demo.

Comment: It looks like that was the problem - bootstrap 4/5 or may have had an incorrect integrity code. Thank you for the help - still learning the ropes. It is working now.